# how to get the date from the list of numbers of this format: 14302610302017, i.e., time + date

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have the following dataframe, how can I get the date from the list for each element use simple code rather than the loop. for example,

```
a    152010302017
a    152009302017
a    132010312017
a     72010302017
b    143010302017
b    123010302017
b     93010302017
c    143010302017
```

I want to get the date:

```
10302017
09302017
......
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string methods to slice the datetime

```
df['date']= df['datetime'].astype(str).str[-8:]

0    10302017
1    09302017
2    10312017
3    10302017
4    10302017
5    10302017
6    10302017
7    10302017
```